# Permissions Error with PyInstaller (running as admin)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am having some problems with using **PyInstaller** to package a project. I have used it successfully in the past for simpler scripts, but I am attempting to package a larger project (pyqt4 gui that calls multiple scrips and modules) and I get the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\bincache01_py27_64bi\qt4_plugins\imageformats\qsvg4.dll'

I'm running `pyinstaller` from a command prompt with admin privileges. I've checked the permission on the file in question and I definitely have all permissions for that file.

I haven't been able to find anything that's helped, most of the people reporting similar issues seemed to solved them by running from a command prompt with admin privileges. If anyone has any ideas or advice that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the file in use and locked by a process?

Comment: As far as I can tell it isn't, I can't find anything running that I can imagine would be using it. However, I just checked it again and it seems that the  file is 0kb and it prevents me from moving it to a different location. So it seems like maybe its copying that file from elsewhere and the file is getting corrupted or something in that process.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, `pyinstaller -F script.py` without the `build` on the command prompt worked for me.