# Python script work fine. but when i convert it to exe show errors

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script **Rad.py** works just fine, But i have problems when I convert it to .exe
I use **pyinstaller** to convert py to exe

It give me an error :
`with open('stat.txt', 'a') as f:`
`permissionerror errno 13 permission denied : stat.txt 7804 failed to execute script`

even when I run it as administrator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission Error When Trying to Use PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778203/permission-error-when-trying-to-use-pyinstaller)

Comment: pyinstaller work juste fine for me. but the exe file work just to until a point show me an error

Comment: you can take a look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560179/permissions-error-with-pyinstaller-running-as-admin, otherwise I suggest re-installing the latest version of pyinstaller and following the build directions.